Challenging the distinction between a validity and a tautology
I know that there is a formal difference between a validity and a tautology. On the one hand, a validity is any formula of First-Order Logic that is true in all interpretations. A tautology is a propositional validity that is true solely based off of the form of a statement that it takes.
I suggest a way to challenge this paradigm, but for modal logic, as opposed to first order logic. That is, in modal logic, say in S4, the following is a validity, but not a tautology:

◊◊A→◊A

However, given logics like Intuitionism that couch modal language in purely propositional language, it seems to me that the line between validity and tautology gets blurred.
Take for example the following axiomatization for S4:
(B→C)→(A→(B→C))
(A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C))
(A∧B)→A
(A∧B)→B
(A→B)→((A→C)→(A→(B∧C)))
(A∧∼A)→B
((A∧∼B)→B)→(A→B)
From A and (A→B), infer B
□A:=((A→A)→A)
◊A:=∼□∼A

In the above, ‘→’ is strict implication, while classical implication may be defined as ∼(A∧∼B).
It seems to me that in the above system, a formula that corresponds to a validity of modal logic would be considered a propositional tautology of the above axiom system.
For example,

∼(A→B)→◊∼B

corresponds to

∼∼(A∧∼B)→∼((B→B)→B)

which is a tautology of the above axiom system, when viewed as a propositional logic unto itself.
Is there a blur between a tautology and a validity at the level of modal logic, given translations like Gödel-McKinsey-Tarski? Is modal logic reducible to purely propositional reasoning after all?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
